# Hashi-vault with Keycloak: error checking oidc discovery URL: error creating provider with given values: NewProvider: unable to create provider: oidc

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

We are trying to integrate Hashi Vault with Keycloak via enabling/configuring Oidc method in our vault using UI.

1. Configured the realm and client for Hashi vault in keycloak with valid callback urls
2. Enabled OIDC in vault UI and configured OIDC with valid OIDC discovery URL, OIDC client ID ,OIDC client secret  and the OIDC discovery CA PEM.

We are getting below error for our given OIDC discovery URL.

```
error checking oidc discovery URL: error creating provider with given values: NewProvider: unable to create provider: oidc: failed to decode provider discovery object: expected Content-Type = application/json, got "text/html;charset=utf-8": invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

OIDC discovery URL : https://keycloak.xxx-yyyyyy.com/admin/master/console/#/realms/test

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue asked above. I am using OAuth2 proxy and my IDP is keycloak. Error I get is exactly the same

```
error while discovery OIDC configuration: failed to discover OIDC configuration: error performing request: Get "https://example.com/auth/realms/******/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

Although when I curl the URL "https://example.com/auth/realms/******/.well-known/openid-configuration", it returns the config successfully

I really need some help here.